# Expected Value for summing over distinct random integers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $L=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k\}$ be a random (uniformly chosen) subset of length $k$ of the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. I want to find $E(X)$ where $X$ is the random variable that sums all numbers. We might want that $k < n$ too.

My main problem is that I cannot get the function $q(a,k,n)$ that gives me the number of ways to write the number $a$ as the sum of exactly $k$ distinct addends less or equal $n$. [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) seems related but it doesn't limit the size of the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expectation of each of the terms in the sum is $(n+1)/2$ so the expectation is $k(n+1)/2$.

If you want to calculate the function $q(a,k,n)$ then you can use [my Java applet here](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm), by choosing "Partitions with distinct terms of:" $a$, "Exact number of terms:"$k$, "Each term no more than:" $n$, and then click on the "Calculate" button. If instead you start with "Compositions with distinct terms of:", then you will get a figure $k!$ times as big.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this one because I think your great applet can be useful for me on later tasks too :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: (1) Compute $E(a_1)$. (2) Show that $E(a_k)=E(a_1)$ for every $k$. (3) Deduce $E(X)$.

This is a good example where computing the distribution is messy but computing the expectation is easy.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad I cannot accept two answers as both answers together answer my questions completely :)